# Return ajax value when going to prev page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax running to get some data based on a dropdown field. This works, but when i filter and go to a detail page and go back to the prev page. i see all the items again but the item in de dropdown still displays the last checked filter.

When i try to get this data with jquery it says the first option is active but it displays whatever option i selected last time.

DROPDOWN:

```
<select class="input-filter" id="filter-countries" name="cbo-country">
  <option value="0"><?= $this->lang->line('all_countries') ?></option>
  <?php
  foreach($vacancies_countries as $c){
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $c->id ?>"><?= $c->{'name_'.LANG} ?></option>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

AJAX function:

```
function initFilters(){
  $('#filter-countries').on('change', function(){
    var country_id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: site_url + 'jobs/filter',
      data: {
        country_id: country_id
      },
      success: function(res){
        $('.vacancies-holder').html(res);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Is there a way to only show the items of the selected dropdown or remove the dropdown label to 'show all'?

As you can see when i return, the dropdown shows 'germany' (witch is ID : 2) but in fact i get the first ID even tho the display says 'germany'

[Visual of the problemeN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keoKv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could run this on page load

```
$('#filter-countries option:first').prop('selected', true);`
```

If you've already called `initFilters` by then you may need this after `var country_id = $(this).val();` to prevent triggering the action.

```
if (!country_id) {
    return;
}
```